# Find identical values in a column of a dataframe and create a new dataframe with each duplicate

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm relatively new to Python and searching for an answer to my problem the whole day already, but unfortunately could't find anything.

I import data to python from an excel file and create a dataframe with it. The Data is a long list with customers and their payments. The column Account (which represents the customer as their customer number) has many duplicates, since the customers usually buy not only one product.

I would like to look through that Account column, take all identical Account numbers and create a new dataframe with all these rows. That for example I have a new Dataframe with all the rows which had account number 10000, the next dataframe with 10001 and so on.

Can somebody help me with that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you edit your question and put there sample (small) input data and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, something like this will help. Let's assume `df_customer` is your dataframe.

**Code:**

```py
cntr=1
for i in df_customer['Account'].unique():
    locals()['df_customer'+str(cntr)]=df_customer[df_customer['Account'] == i]
    cntr += 1
```

What the above code will do is create a new dataframe (`df_customer1`,`df_customer2`,`df_customer3` etc) for every account number in the dataframe.

To check the number of dataframes created, you can check the final value of `cntr`.

Do let me know if this is what you intended to do!

Comment: Edit! It works now. I just have to figure out if this already delivers me my result I need.

Comment: Your answer is the first step to my goal. Now that I have n number of df, I need to do a small calculation (divison) in each df and then put the result of each divsion together with the account number all together in one new data frame. So that in the end you have an overview over all the unique account numbers and the division.

Comment: Awesome! You can add the step for calculation below `locals()[...]` step. Just reference the dataframe inside the loop as `locals()['df_customer'+str(cntr)]`.

Comment: Damn, I am just too new to python to understand what you try to tell me. I have to sum the Column "Amount" and "Sum_Product" and then divide the Sum_Product sum by the Sum of Amount. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: And do you want to create a new column with the values ? It would be helpful if you can edit your question to show a sample of your dataframe and the required output!

Comment: Preferably just a variable since it is only one number for each dataframe, not for each row. So even when the Dataframes have 2000 rows, I am only interested in the result for dividing sum of product by sum of amount. After that I just have to have an overview that for example Customer 100001 = 49.59, Customer 100002 = 50.24 and so on.

Comment: Is `sum_product` a column ? You can do this: `locals()['var'+str(cntr)] = locals()['df_customer'+str(cntr)]['Sum_Product'].sum()/locals()['df_customer'+str(cntr)]['Amount'].sum()`

Comment: Yes, it is a column. So Column amount contains values I need to sum up before the division and Sum_product contains values I need to sum up first. And these two sums form the division then.

Comment: Write that piece of code above `cntr += 1`. It will create a variable (`var1`,`var2` etc) which will have the value of the calculation.

Comment: The error you see must be because you already created the 82 dataframes previously. So cntr value is no longer 1. Refresh the code and try again and it should work.

Comment: You are great! until now everything works fine. I just have to figure out what exactly I have to do now with the variables. If I can't manage it i would love to ask you another question then. Thanks you so much!

Comment: When you say create new dataframe with the values, do you mean that dataframe will just have the name and the calculation as the columns ?

Comment: Sure! Try it out and post another question if you can't get it. Tag me in comments! Please do upvote this answer too :)

Comment: Yes, now that I have all the values in the variables, I just have to put them together to the account number. That in the end I can list the value for each unique account number. I am not sure how I can now match the variables with the account numbers. The only match by order now.

Comment: If you want the account number as the name of the dataframe, you can do that. Replace `cntr` with `i` in this code: `locals()['df_customer'+str(cntr)]`. You won't need a `cntr` in this case. However, it will be hard for you to know the number of dataframes created!

Comment: I have a separate df with only the unique Account numbers. So there must be exactly that many account numbers that there are variables now. Since the order hasn't changed, the first variable must match the first account number. It would be great to just create a new data frame with the account numbers in the first column and all the variables created by your code as the second column.

Comment: I see. All these could have been done in one step without creating multiple dataframes :)

Comment: :( And there's the problem that I am brand new to that. If you have an easier idea, please let me know!

Comment: `df_customer['Calculation'] = df_customer.groupby('Account')['Sum_Product'].transform('sum') / df_customer.groupby('Account')['Amount'].transform('sum')` This would give you a new column with the required value per account code.

Comment: Apply the code above to your main `df`. A new column called `calculation` will have the required value. It will be the same for the same account code.